# Create INTERSECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, intersection

I have a tables

`ppv (product_id | property_id | value_id)`

and

`v (id | property_id | value)`

I try to make query to get `products` where:

```
select product_id from v, ppv as t INNER JOIN ppv as t2 
ON t.product_id = t2.product_id and t1.property_id = t2.property_id
where
( t1.property_id = 1 and v.value > $a and v.value < $b )
and
( t2.property_id = 2 and v.value > $c and v.value < $d )
```

But havn`t any results. Please help.

So,

```
ppv (product_id | property_id | value_id)
 1              1            50
 1              2            2
 1              3            3
 2              1            28
 2              2            2
 2              3            29
```

Next table

```
v( id | property_id | value)
 2          2           3
 3          3           2
 28         1           2600000
 29         3           3
 50         1           2500000
```

---

### **  I found a solution to this problem in this way  **

```
SELECT `product_id`, 
       CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(v.`property_id`) USING cp1251) as properties
FROM `values` as v INNER JOIN `product_property_values` as ppv
ON ppv.value_id = v.id
WHERE
   (v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2500000 and v.value <= 3000000 ) 
   or 
   (v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 3 )
GROUP by product_id
HAVING LOCATE('1', properties) and LOCATE('2', properties)
```

Th result:

*test 1*

```
v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2500000 and v.value < 3000000
v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 2

 product_id properties
 Empty
```

*test2*

```
v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2550000 and v.value < 3000000
v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 4

product_id  properties
     2          2,1
```

*test3*

```
v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2000000 and v.value < 3000000
v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 4

product_id  properties
     1          1,2
     2          2,1
```

**It's OK!**

Comment: yes, I need to get Products where isset proprety-1 and propeerty-2/ If any property not exist when skeep product

Comment: You need to give more details, or perhaps an example of the result you expect given a certain data set. If your query doesn't work, you can't explain what you want by only showing it!

Comment: Okey. I Try to detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `product_id`, 
       CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(v.`property_id`) USING cp1251) as properties
FROM `values` as v INNER JOIN `product_property_values` as ppv
ON ppv.value_id = v.id
WHERE
   (v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2500000 and v.value <= 3000000 ) 
   or 
   (v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 3 )
GROUP by product_id
HAVING LOCATE('1', properties) and LOCATE('2', properties)
```

Th result:

*test 1*

```
v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2500000 and v.value < 3000000
v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 2

 product_id properties
 Empty
```

*test2*

```
v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2550000 and v.value < 3000000
v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 4

product_id  properties
     2          2,1
```

*test3*

```
v.`property_id` = 1 and v.value >= 2000000 and v.value < 3000000
v.`property_id` = 2 and v.value >= 1 and v.value <= 4

product_id  properties
     1          1,2
     2          2,1
```

**It's OK!**

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are actually joining table `v`.  Also, I don't believe it is necessary to link to `ppv` twice.  Try:

```
SELECT ppv.product_id
FROM v
INNER JOIN ppv ON v.property_id = ppv.property_id
WHERE
(ppv.property_id = 1 and v.value > $a and v.value < $b )
OR
(ppv.property_id = 2 and v.value > $c and v.value < $d )
```

Comment: Try to do. The result of running does not correspond to the desired =(

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:** what is `t1` ?

**Second problem:**

- `t1.property_id = t2.property_id`
- `t1.property_id = 1`
- `t2.property_id = 2`

Which means : `1 = 2`.

---

If I understand well, you're looking for products which have :

- a `property_id = 1` set
- a `property_id = 2` set
- a value superior to `$a` if `property_id = 1` exists
- a value superior to `$c` if `property_id = 2` exists
- a value inferior to `$b` if `property_id = 1` exists
- a value inferior to `$d` if `property_id = 2` exists

I think you're looking for this request :

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM v
JOIN ppv as t1 ON v.product_id = t1.product_id AND t1.property_id = 1
JOIN ppv as t2 ON v.product_id = t2.product_id AND t2.property_id = 2
WHERE v.value > GREATEST($a, $c)
  AND v.value < LEAST($b, $d)
```